# How to rewrite a tricky system of DEs into a 'normal' system of 1st order DEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I know how to rewrite systems of 2nd order DEs to a system of 1st order DEs and would like to do the same with this system:
\begin{align}
a x' + b y' + c x & = z(t) \\
d x' + e y' + f y & = 0
\end{align}
where a to f are constants.

EDIT:

Proposed solution in a now deleted comment was to isolate like this:
\begin{align}
x' & = \frac{z(t) - b y' - c x}{a}  \\
y' & = \frac{- d x' - f y}{e}
\end{align}

and then insert them into the original system like this:
\begin{align}
a x' + b \frac{- d x' - f y}{e} + c x & = z(t) \\
d \frac{z(t) - b y' - c x}{a} + e y' + f y & = 0
\end{align}

and then carry on from there.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have a system of two linear equations in two unknowns: $ax'+by'=-cx+z,dx'+ey'=-fy$. You need to solve this system of equations, using any method. Cramer's rule is probably easiest here, due to the system being small and fully symbolic. However, you can carry out your substitution argument by rearranging those two equations to get $x'=...$ and $y'=...$ respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost done. Isolate $x'$ and $y'$ on the left hand side of the equalities. For instance
$$
a\,x' + b \frac{- d\,x' - f\,y}{e} + c\,x = z(t)\implies \Bigl(a-\frac{b\,d}{e}\Bigr)x'=-c\,x+\frac{b\,f}{e}\,y+z(t).
$$
Observe that this is solving the original system for $x'$ and $y'$.

Comment: Yes, it does the trick, thank you.